# Sequence convergence involving an extra $λ \in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $λ \in (0,1)$. We define the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ with
$$x_{n+1}=λ\ln (1+x_n)+(1-λ)\ln x_n$$
for $n\geq1$. Study the convergence of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $(nx_n)_{n\geq 1}$.
I have started with this lemma:
If $a,b \in R $ with $a<b$ then $λb+(1-λ)a \in (a,b).$
So I consider $x_{2}=λ\ln (1+x_1)+(1-λ)\ln x_1 \in (\ln x_1,\ln (1+x_1) )$, where $\ln (1+x_1)=b$ and $\ln x_1=a$. I want to know if I'm on the right track or could someone please give me a hint.

Comment: This sequence quickly becomes undefined, as $x_n < 0$ and $x_{n+1}$ can't be computed.

Comment: $x_n>0$ because otherwise we can't have $\ln x_n$

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. For any starting point $x_0$, there is some $n$, s.t. $x_n \leq 0$.

Comment: You are saying that the problem is wrong?

Comment: I have no proof, but I experimented on computer and it happend all the times

Comment: If $\lambda =\frac 1 2$ and $x_1=\frac 1 2$ then $x_2 <0$ so $x_3$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First $x_n>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Using
$$ \ln(1+x)<x, \text{ for }x>0 $$
one has 
$$\ln x_1\le x_2\le \ln(1+x_1)\le x_1. $$
Suppose $x_n\le x_{n-1}$. Then
$$ x_{n+1}=\lambda\ln(1+x_n)+(1-\lambda)\ln x_n\le\ln(1+x_n)\le x_n.$$
By induction, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$ x_{n+1}\le x_n, $$
namely, 
$$ x_1\ge x_2\ge\cdots\ge x_n\ge x_{n+1}\ge \cdots>0.$$
So $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and monotonic and hence it converges. Clearly the limit must be positive. So $\{nx_n\}$ diverges.